# JavaScript click handler for row receives cell as target

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a multi-column, multi-row table. Each row has a unique "data-index" attribute. I added a click event listener on each row. However, when I click on the row, the cell I happen to be over when I click becomes the target for the callback. In order to get the "data-index" attribute, I must use `event.target.parentElement.getAttribute( "data-index" )`

Consider this ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr data-index="0" onclick="handler(event)">
        <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="1" onclick="handler(event)">
        <td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="2" onclick="handler(event)">
        <td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      function handler ( event ) {
        console.log( event.target.innerText );
        console.log( event.target.getAttribute( "data-index" ) );
        console.log( event.target.parentElement.getAttribute( "data-index" ) );
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just to be clear; I'm interested in the row, not its cells. It's the row that "owns" the data attribute, so ...

Why is the event target the cell and not the row? (*None* of the cells have event listeners.) At the very least, this is very unintuitive; am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The "target" property tells you the element where the event happened. That's the way it's supposed to work. You can use "currentTarget" to get the element relative to the handler assignment.

Comment: I usually attach ONE event handler to the table. In the handler I look at the target, and if it isn't the row, I use parentElement to traverse until I find the nodeName TR or get the table or NULL. And I put the data in a WeakMap with the table row as index.

Comment: The target is the element that you clicked on. It could be a TD, or if you have a SPAN inside the TD it is the SPAN, BUTTON or any other element that you have put in a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.currentTarget` instead. `target` is the element triggered the event (you can't click the row since the cells are inside it and cover the row preventing from being clicked directly).

```html
    <table>
      <tr data-index="0" onclick="handler(event)">
        <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="1" onclick="handler(event)">
        <td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="2" onclick="handler(event)">
        <td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      function handler ( event ) {
        console.log( event.currentTarget.innerText );
        console.log( event.currentTarget.getAttribute( "data-index" ) );
        console.log( event.currentTarget.parentElement.getAttribute( "data-index" ) );
      }
    </script>
```

Another way is to use `event.target.closest('tr')` to find a td's tr:

```html
    <table>
      <tr data-index="0" onclick="handler(event)">
        <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="1" onclick="handler(event)">
        <td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="2" onclick="handler(event)">
        <td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      function handler ( event ) {
        const $tr = event.target.closest('tr');
        console.log( $tr.innerText );
        console.log( $tr.getAttribute( "data-index" ) );
        console.log( $tr.parentElement.getAttribute( "data-index" ) );
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: This was actually helpful. Thank you.